# With a as () what is it mean?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

this is a  single code , but i divided it into 3 parts for describing .

i used  "With a as "
My question is :
What is its name ? is it a function or what ?

Because i want google it for more explanation about it

```
with a as (
```

```
 select 
             count(e.department_id) as cnt, 
             (select count(*) from employees e,departments d where e.department_id=d.department_id) as b_cnt 
      from employees e
      group by e.department_id,e.employee_id
     )
```

```
select 
       sum(cnt) as cnt,
       sum(b_cnt) as b_cnt
from a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's commonly known as CTE (Common Table Expression), but in oracle docs you can find it as *[Subquery Factoring clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF30048)*

More examples:

- https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause
- https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2
- https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1

Answer (score 0):

it's a with clause

> The WITH clause, or subquery factoring clause, is part of the SQL-99
> standard and was added into the Oracle SQL syntax in Oracle 9.2. The
> WITH clause may be processed as an inline view or resolved as a
> temporary table. The advantage of the latter is that repeated
> references to the subquery may be more efficient as the data is easily
> retrieved from the temporary table, rather than being requeried by
> each reference. You should assess the performance implications of the
> WITH clause on a case-by-case basis.

you can read more here:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause

Answer (score 0):

The SQL WITH clause was introduced by Oracle in the Oracle 9i release 2 database. The SQL WITH clause allows you to give a sub-query block a name, which can be referenced in several places within the main SQL query.

**Document Link:** 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/172521/difference-between-inline-view-and-with-clause